# Silverlight 4 RichTextBox - can't restore Xaml with text containing curly braces

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, richtextbox

We have a Silverlight application using the RichTextBox as a rich text editor for the user to create emails.

We actually have our own serializer but essentially we are saving and restoring the Xaml. As far as I can tell it is impossible to restore any text containing curly braces.

You can demonstrate this fairly easily by creating a RichTextBox and typing something similar to `{weird}` into it. Then take the .Xaml property of the textbox and set it on the .Xaml property of another textbox - kablooie.

As we have our own serializer I have tried escaping the Text member of the Run elements with `<Run Text="{} the real {Text} here" />`. This makes no difference. I've tried replacing the braces with &#123; but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acknowledging the issue here and checking with the team.  If the Run *starts* with curly braces it appears to throw a value exception.  I'm investigating.

Answer (score 1):

This issue also occurs in the Windows Phone 7 (Mango) `RichTextBox`. I found a [workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098250/display-curly-braces-in-richtextbox-when-manually-setting-xaml-property) which consists of putting a zero-width non-joiner `&#8204;` character at the beginning and end of each `Run`. As opposed to using the zero-width space this also works if you have an opening curly brace at the beginning *and* a closing curly brace at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a xml problem.  Have you tried encapsulating your data in a CDATA block to encapsulate any special characters?

```
<richtext>

    <![CDATA[
    function matchwo(a,b)
    {
    if (a < b && a < 0) then
      {
      return 1;
      }
    else
      {
      return 0;
      }
    }
    ]]>

<richtext>
```

Comment: Putting the Run Text inside a CDATA block isn't supported by the Silverlight XamlReader unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A Silverlight developer has confirmed this as a bug. It happens if the Run Text starts with a '{' or a space followed by '{'. Because we have our own serializer I can insert a zero width space (&#8203;) at the start of every run which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try escaping with `{}{weird}`(open and closed curly braces)

Comment: Doesn't help (we tried that first - I should have mentioned it in the question). The problem is a bug in the Silverlight RichTextBox.