# Display curly braces in RichTextBox when manually setting Xaml property

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, richtextbox

I'm currently working on a Twitter app for Windows Phone, in which – via a custom `DependencyProperty` – the `Xaml` property of each [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is bound to the text of a tweet (which includes programmatically generated `Run` elements with all the text). This works good enough until there are curly braces `{` and `}` in the text. I tried replacing them with `&#123;` and escaping with `{}` but to no avail.

The weird thing is, if the curly braces show up in the middle of the text (more specifically, in the `Text` property of a `Run` element) everything's fine, it's only when an opening curly brace is at the beginning* *or* a closing curly brace is at the end* that the `RichTextBox` crashes. I was able to work around this by inserting zero-width spaces with `&#8203;` at the beginning and end of each `Run`.

However, this issue gets more complicated if there is both an opening curly brace at the beginning* *and* a closing curly brace at the end*. In that case, the zero-width spaces don't seem to work anymore, so the only workaround would be to insert additional "real" characters at either the beginning or end of the text, which I obviously can't do.

This does seem to be a bug with `RichTextBox`, as acknowledged in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999782/silverlight-4-richtextbox-cant-restore-xaml-with-text-containing-curly-braces/2999864#2999864) over two years ago. Apparently, it hasn't been fixed yet. So, does anyone know of any further workarounds I could try?

* can also be preceeded only by whitespace or followed only by whitespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay after some more tinkering I found an easy fix. Just put a ["zero-width non-joiner"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) character `&#8204;` (`&zwnj;` doesn't work in XAML) at the beginning and end of each `Run`.

Apparently this character is treated differently than the zero-width space I used previously and even works if your text has curly braces at both the beginning *and* the end. There are of course even more invisible characters that have the same effect (check [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)) but the zero-width non-joiner should have the least side-effects I think.